# Jasperreports Server: Reports not shown via REST

Tags: api, rest, jasperserver

I use the Jasperreports Server CE. I have logged on to the webinterface and made a new report.

When I request the list of reports, the new report is not shown.

```
http://mymachine:myport/jasperserver/rest_v2/reports
```

only returns an empty response body. HTTP status is 204.

How can I access/list reports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. It seems, like myself, you have the same wrong expectation as I had: I assumed that

```
GET http://<host>:<port>/jasperserver/rest_v2/reports
```

would list all reports, as that was my expectation from working with other REST APIs. This assumption was wrong.

After playing around and reading the manual more carefully than before, I eventually got it right. Calling `reports` is only used to retrieve a specific report (don't forget the file extension, e.g `.pdf` in my case):

```
GET http://<host>:<port>/jasperserver/rest_v2/reports/<folderpath>/<reportname>.pdf
```

In order to get *all reports* you need to use request `resources` instead instead of `reports`. This will return all resources:

```
GET http://<host>:<port>/jasperserver/rest_v2/resources/
```

To *only* list reports, you can filter by type (and optionally also just check a subfolder):

```
GET http://<host>:<port>/jasperserver/rest_v2/resources/<folderpath>?type=reportUnit&recursive=1
```